# Decoding UTF-8 to URL with Python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I have the following url encoded in utf-8.

```
url_input = u'https://www.gumtree.com//p/uk-holiday-rentals/1bedroon-flat-\xa3250pw-all-bills-included-/1174092955'
```

I need to scrap this webpage and to do so I need to have the following url_output (unicode is not read).

```
url_output=https://www.gumtree.com//p/uk-holiday-rentals/1bedroon-flat-£250pw-all-bills-included-/1174092955
```

When I print url_input, I get url_output:

```
print(url_input)
https://www.gumtree.com//p/uk-holiday-rentals/1bedroon-flat-£250pw-all-bills-included-/1174092955
```

However I do not find a way to transform url_input to url_output. According to forums the print function uses ascii decoding on Python 2.7 but ascii is not supposed to read `\xa3` and `url_input.encode('ASCII')` does not work.

Does someone know how I can solve this problem ? 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some tests, I can confirm that the server accepts the URL in different formats:

- raw utf8 encoded URL:

  ```
  url_output = url_input.encode('utf8')
  ```
- %encoded latin1 URL

  ```
  url_output = urllib.quote_plus(url_input.encode('latin1'), '/:')
  ```
- %encoded utf8 URL

  ```
  url_output = urllib.quote_plus(url_input.encode('utf8'), '/:')
  ```

As the raw latin1 in not accepted and leads to an incorrect URL error, and as passing non ascii characters in an URL may not be safe, my advice is to use this third way. It gives:

```
    print url_output

    https://www.gumtree.com//p/uk-holiday-rentals/1bedroon-flat-%C2%A3250pw-all-bills-included-/1174092955
```

Answer (score 2):

When you print `url_input` you get the desired `url_output` only because your terminal understand UTF-8 and can represents `\xa3` correctly.

You can encode the string in ASCII with `str.encode`, but you have to replace (with a `?`) or ignore the chars that does not are ascii:

```
url_output = url_input.encode("ascii", "replace")
print(url_output)
```

will prints:

```
https://www.gumtree.com//p/uk-holiday-rentals/1bedroon-flat-?250pw-all-bills-included-/1174092955
```

and

```
url_output = url_input.encode("ascii", "ignore")
print(url_output)
```

will prints:

```
https://www.gumtree.com//p/uk-holiday-rentals/1bedroon-flat-250pw-all-bills-included-/1174092955
```

You can not obtain an output string with a `£` ascii character because the value of this character is greater than 127.

Comment: thanks for your answer, It becomes clearer. So you think I need to find the good encoding input for Gumtree website to get the good webpage ?

Comment: where the input come from? maybe this can be an hint on how to decode this string.